# Should users be rewarded with privileges/reputation from very little contribution?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

There are many old questions which earn the asker [a ton of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for very little effort. Over 12k from less than 2 minutes of work!

Is it correct that we award these users with so much reputation or moderator privileges? Whereas, many users spend a lot of time on less popular, higher-effort posts, or rewardless editing, and have *less* privileges than the aforementioned one-question ponies!

I realize that a variant of the `high reputation != good moderator` debate, but it is fairly pronounced in this case, so I thought I would pose a new question.

Comment: It's especially bad if that's their only question. If they DID decide to come back, they wouldn't know what to do with their powers.

Comment: There was a dupe question for this just 1-2 weeks ago.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ probably every 1-2 weeks recurring.

Comment: Why should a user that asked a very useful question not get reputation for doing so? where do we draw the line?

Comment: @KevinB But there are sub 100 rep users that have put more effort into this site than that person! Even disregarding the reputation issue, the user should certainly not be awarded with privileges.

Comment: Note that the votes it received happened over a very long period, i seriously doubt the user hit 12k overnight from that question. It appears to have accumulated over the course of two years, even though the question was asked almost four years ago.

Comment: This is also likely a VERY rare exception where a user happened to ask the right question at the right time. Implementing some kind of  system that would prevent such a rare occasion from resulting in reputation/privileges seems like a waste of time.

Comment: I would like to hear from those sub-100 rep users after a few years of accumulating points, and see if they appreciate this (non-)feature.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You can't, basically by definition.  People only ever notice it when the user isn't active.  Jon Skeet has *several* questions that would have earned him *thousands* of rep each, if he wasn't always hitting the rep cap every day from other questions, and yet this (justifiably so) doesn't tend to bother most anyone.  You only ever notice it when it's irrelevant.

Comment: This should (continue to) be treated from the opposite end. If they abuse the privileges, they lose them.

Answer (score 2):

Single handed moderation privileges are limited to those elected, and those who have through earning a gold badge shown they are at least dedicated to their tag.

The only thing that user can do now that they couldn't before, without getting agreement from other members, is edit. Edits bump posts in the active queue and if such a user (or, well, any user) were seen to be abusing their powers you can hope and / or trust that the elected moderators will deal with it appropriately.

It's such a hypothetical edge case that it's not worth worrying about, unless it becomes an actual problem.

There have been suggestions to tie privileges to activity, rather than rep (such as require x validated off topic flags to vtc), but they all seem to fall flat and / or get declined as needlessly complicating the system.

Comment: Unfortunate, as I have suffered many a sleepless night due to this. :/