# About having a maximum reputation for a user and specific questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation

In my opinion, the reputation should be a indication of knowledge and helpfulness.

Currently, many of the questions asked some 6-8 years ago about very broad topics have a high score. Authors of those questions and answers have high rank and gold tags of those topics, even if in some cases, they do not have a good understanding of it.

An example? Take myself: out of my current 4K points, 1.7K come from a single stupid date formatting question in JavaScript. There are much more extreme cases that I will not point out by respect. Do you really think that asking about some basic/general topic 6 years ago indicate any knowledge or helpfulness?

In my opinion, the reputation given by a single question or answer should be limited to a few tens of votes, so persons with high score really correlate with many good answers. The answer could have many votes, but the user score should not be increased further.

Relates:

*[Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions)*

Comment: 1. IMO there are posts that deserve tens of thousands of votes. 2. Reputation is not an accurate measure of someone's knowledge or expertise.

Comment: Something basic has presumably helped lots of people over those 6 years so why doesn't it deserve it?

Comment: The question/Answer deserve the score, but asking a question in the early SO age does not. Here we are just giving reputation for to the fact of asking early.

Comment: On feature requests a down vote means: Don't implement this, on discussions a down vote means: I disagree with the premises of the question.

Comment: It's *very* doubtful whether you actually earned 1,700 points from that answer. Don't forget the 200-point daily limit.

Comment: Maybe some of the down votes are caused by the one-sided research you did: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321816

Comment: IMO there are posts that deserve tens of thousands of negative votes

Comment: see also: [Life isn't fair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652/165773)

Comment: @gnat: nothing about being fair or not. Just about, just about  looking at me in the glass in the morning and thinking: "I told them, now it's their problem".

Answer (score 6):

I don't disagree this is unfair, but so far no one has managed to come up with a good solution to this that doesn't have some insane downside.

A per-question reputation limit to replace the 200-point daily cap [was suggested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/) - by none other than our #1 user, Jon Skeet.

It turned out that implementing it [would favour the high-rep users *even more*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136293/138112). So if the goal is to reduce the rep gain of veteran users, that's not an option.

> Take myself: out of my current 4K points, 1.7K come from a single stupid date formatting question in JavaScript.

It's probably less than that. The 200-point daily cap has probably swallowed a fair chunk of the theoretical 1,700 points that come from 170 votes.

I had several such very trivial, highly voted answers in my profile. I asked to have them disassociated from my account a few years ago, I was applying for a job and embarrassed by those answers sticking out. That option is always open to everyone (although it of course doesn't solve the broader issue if you believe one to be there).