# How can I find all duplicates for question marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

It is so, that sometimes we can have a chain(or may be a graph) of duplicates (please correct me, if I am wrong). So you find a Question1_4, it is a duplicate of(points to) Question1_3, which has a couple of not accepted answers and is a duplicate of Question1_2, on which point some other duplicates Question2_1 and Question2_2.

**Is there a way to find all relevant duplicates so that you don't need to go manually through the graph?**

You can ask: "Why do you need to see the duplicates?!" The answer is simple - the answers are different and so I can find which one is more suitable for my conditions.

Comment: So what's the problem with simply clicking the link at the top of the page to see the next duplicate in the chain?

Comment: The "Linked" question list on the right might get you close

Comment: @KevinB If I am not mistaken "Linked" are relevant for current question, not all duplicates will be shown there.

Comment: It means exactly what it says, "Linked". if the current question is "linked" within another question/answer, it'l show up in the linked list. It's not just for dupes, but can certainly help you find alternative answers to your question.

Comment: @Servy If there is a graph, then it is easy to get lost in it, what you have already seen and what not.

Comment: @Rekshino How so?  You read through the question, then you go onto the next, then you go onto the next, and eventually you reach the end.  It's *super* rare to have a chain longer than 2, and it's a singly linked list that can't have cycles, so it's pretty hard to get lost in that.

Comment: @Servy since there could be multiple duplicates it is at least a tree starting from a question to all duplicates. I really hope that "edit duplicates" feature can't create cycles... (Indeed cases when there are more than couple questions in whole tree are very rare and getting lost there *should* be hard)

Comment: @Servy Really rear? Take a look on a question for today https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349238/about-having-a-maximum-reputation-for-a-user-and-specific-questions-answers  And if you want to see the linked questions, then for me it is easy to lose an overview

Comment: @Rekshino How is finding *one* question mean it's not rare?  I didn't say it was impossible or never happened, just that it's rare.  And how is it difficult to read through that question's duplicates?

Comment: @Servy It would be easier for me to have an overview of all relevant duplicates and not to click through.

Comment: @Rekshino So in extremely rare instances you might be able to turn a situation that's trivially easy into something that's a little bit easier.  Still not seeing how that's worthwhile.

Comment: @Servy If I ask it and if it annoys me, to click through, then it's a worthwhile for me(amazing, that you don't see such a simple thing). If we will not endeavor to improve(may be also simple) things, then we will not achieve a progress.

Comment: @Rekshino Why spend considerable development effort saving a tiny fraction of the site's userbase just a few clicks when you could spend that same development time making improvements that will affect millions of people, rather than hundreds, and improvements that will do more than save a click or two (because there are lots of problems that the site has that do more than make you click once or twice more than you'd like a few times in your entire life).

Comment: @Servy I have not an overview how many problems the site has and which impact the solution for one or another problem has. I have asked a question to know, whether there is such a possibility and if not, then, when all BIG problems solved :) , it would be (in my opinion!) not bad to have such a possibility.